# How to link two paragraphs of a different indentation format (python docx)?

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm trying to build a SINGLE paragraph in a created word docx (via python docx) which looks like this:

```
text       kjdfkjshfkjshfdkjhskjdhf
           kjdhfksdfkhsgfdghsf
           ksjdgfkjsgkjfgjsgf
```

The thing is that I need to make sure that this paragraph doesn't get broken apart if there is not enough remaining space of the actual page to print all of it on one single page. I thus need to link three paragraphs to reach what I want (to be able to indent the first line of the paragraph in the middle which is a must; the upper and lower lines are simply built without indentation with underscores). This however didn't work when I simply built three paragraphs, and set the `.paragraph_format.keep_together`, as well as the `.paragrapgh_format.keep_with_next modules = True`, for the first two paragraphs (for the last one only `.paragraph_format.keep_together` has been `set = True`). The execution of the code below (relevant part only) works perfectly, the thing is just that the upper and/or lower lines get separated if there's not enough space on the page for all of it, while the middle part doesn't even fill out half of the page (there would be enough space to put all on one page, but it breaks). This tells me that I didn't succeed in linking the three paragraphs with each other. Help? (I'm copying from a word table and content is all copied perfectly as I want; the only problem really is that my paragraph breaks apart).

```
limitor = doc.add_paragraph()
limitor.add_run(separator)
limitor.paragraph_format.keep_together = True
limitor.paragraph_format.keep_with_next = True

ProdPar = doc.add_paragraph()
ProdPar.paragraph_format.keep_together = True
ProdPar.style.font.name = "Times New Roman"
ProdPar.paragraph_format.first_line_indent = Inches(-0.6496)
ProdPar.paragraph_format.left_indent = Inches(0.6496)
ProdPar.add_run(AmountNum + " " + Stücke).bold = True
ProdPar.add_run().add_tab()
table = source.tables[0]
amountofrows = 0
for xx in table.rows:
     amountofrows += 1
rownum = amountofrows - 1
for ab in range(rownum):
       for par in table.rows[ab].cells[1].paragraphs:
              for run in par.runs:
                     copied_run = ProdPar.add_run(run.text)
                     if ab == 0:
                            copied_run.bold=True
                     elif ab == 1:
                            copied_run.italic=True
                     elif ab == 2:
                            copied_run.underline = True
                     if run.text == Spezif:
                            copied_run.italic = True
                            copied_run.underline = True
               ProdPar.add_run("\n")
        ProdPar.add_run("\n")
```

Comment: Are you able to accomplish this with Word by hand, using the application? If not, Word might not support it. If so, it will give clues how to accomplish it with `python-docx`.

Comment: no until yet no success; it corresponds to a hanging indent from upon the second until the second last line of a paragraph....

Comment: What about using first-line-indent of 0.0 and left-indent of 1.3. If there are no blank lines, i.e. no actual need for separate paragraphs, the indenting should get it done for you (all in a single paragraph). Make it work by hand on Word first so you know where to go looking for features in `python-docx`.

Comment: nope indents all the lines to of the paragraph..

Comment: Ah, right, so I think what you need is left-indent of 1.3 and first-line-indent of _minus_ 1.3 (-1.3). I vaguely recall first-line-indent being _relative_ to left-indent, which makes sense when you think about it because that is stable.